# iPhone - "Watermaking" a view on the screen without interfering with touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, watermark

I have some views on wich I'd like to draw some text, with or without transparency, and I'd like this displayed text not to interfere with user touches.

I mean for example, let's say I have a view with a list view and some buttons. I'd like to display on top of the whole thing some text (and some graphics) that does not move, with the list, and that does not catch the touches that the user can make on this text/graphics and let them pass through for exemple to scroll the list view.

How may I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is this, for every UI component:

```
[view setUserinteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This will disable gestures and touches on that component, while leaving the possibility of interacting on everything below/beneath.

So, you can create your "watermark" view, disable interactions, add as a subview to your current view and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a [`CATextLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) as layers don't catch touches. The other graphics can be `CALayer`s too.